# Microsoft Surface Book - Detach screen while off or unpowered?

Tags: microsoft-surface

Does anyone know if the screen of the new **Microsoft Surface Book** will be able to be detached WHILE:

1. It is powered off / in hibernation,
2. Sleeping,
3. It is frozen or hanging,
4. Both batteries (in keyboard and screen) are completely discharged and no power is available for the locking mechanism.

From the hands-on demo videos, it looks like it needs power to unlock the screen while the button is held down and then a desktop message will let you know when it is ready to be pulled off.

**EDIT: Thanks to @FosterMcLaughlin, he reports it is possible to detach while powered off (1), so I assume in (2) and (3) will still detach. The only question now is if it is still possible in (4).**

**EDIT: After visiting a store and seeing the display model, I asked the staff and according to him, if both batteries are discharged completely, you cannot detach the screen as the magnetic locks require power to release. All questions answered! Thanks everyone!**

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone at the event who had hands-on time might have asked about it or tried it.

Comment: laptop batteries are never truly "completely dead" so you may still be able to detach it when the laptop is off and both batteries are supposedly "dead"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I own one and YES you can detach when the book is powered off PROVIDED the tablet section is not completely flat otherwise you will get a error stating there is not enough charge in the tablet to detach.

Comment: This answer is partially correct-you cannot disconnect using the keyboard key while the tablet battery is dead.  However, you can manually disconnect the tablet using paperclips as described in Bob's answer.

Answer (score 6):

On the left and right side there are holes for a manual release.  Just insert a paper clip into the 6th fan-hole from the bottom on each side.

Comment: It was the 5th hole on mine-although it looks like it could vary slightly based on the alignment of the tablet in the keyboard's cradle.  The correct hole was obvious as it was the only one that was deeper than the visible ident.  Also, the paper clip entered at about a 45 degree angle upward.

Comment: This worked for me as well. It's deep, insert paper clip at 45 degree angle and push straight in on both sides of the laptop.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm that inserting paper clip into the 6th fan-hole from the bottom on each side works (my tablet battery was not charging and there was no other way of getting the tablet off the base). You need to insert the paper clip about 2-3 cm deep, at an angle of about 45 degrees upwards. The paperclip will push a lever that is held back by a spring, so you need to apply some small force and push it in by about 0.5cm.

Comment: ❤️ perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

you cannot detach it while off. It requires power to release the connector posts. It also will not disconnect if there is less than 10% battery power. So as for being off, frozen or discharged thats a NO.

Comment: This has been my experience. The above answer was not correct in my case. If I have approximately 15% or less battery, I cannot disconnect my screen. So if I am using it with the screen facing out, and run low on battery, I must either sit and wait for it to charge, or put it in my bag as is - to be scratched. Rather annoying and a poor design choice.

Comment: X This wrong, see the other answers

Answer (score 2):

Even if both batteries are discharged completely, it's possible to detach the screen manualy, with a paper clip.
Just put the paper clip, play around and while you play around try detaching it by lifting it. It's on the left side, around the forth and sixth hole.
[Just like in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuhsq.png)

Comment: Answers which only contain a link to a video are not acceptable.  The video could be removed at any point.  You should take the time to, in specific detail, post all supplemental material within your answer.  This includes any screenshots to explain your directions.

Answer (score 1):

It's the sixth  hole from the hinge and you have to angle the paper clip away from the hinge. also the paper clip goes in 3/4" (further than I would have guessed). The release lever is spring loaded and you can feel the spring giving way as you press.

Answer (score 1):

Surface book 2 - Paper Clip @ 45 Degree Angle based on Post from BOB

---> WORKS, detached SB2, now charging as the keyboard dock is bad.

Answer (score -1):

I am playing around with the surface book right now and, yes you can detach the screen while it is off.

Comment: Thanks, answer accepted. If you ever get the chance to discharge both batteries completely (screen and keyboard batteries), please try it then again and let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I was playing around with a display model from the Microsoft store. So unfortunately I don't think I can wait around for the batteries to die out. I did preorder one thou after. So if it doesn't get answered before then I will get back to you.

Comment: Great, thanks! I assumed that since it detaches while off, it means that a frozen or hanging computer will still be able to detach. The only question remaining is if it can detach when both batteries are completely discharged  and no juice is available for the lock.

Comment: I went in a few days ago to see the display model and according to store staff, if both batteries are discharged completely, you cannot detach it as the magnetic locks need power to release. All answered.